# Find Orthonormal basis of bilinear form $<x,y>=x^{T}Ay$

Tags: linear-algebra

As shown on title the bilinear form $$<x,y>=x^{T}Ay$$, where A is a matrix 2x2 of real numbers which is:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I have to find orthonormal basis of this and I used Gram-Schmidt proccess where:

$u_{1}=v_{1}$; where $v_{1}=(2 \ \ \ 1)^{T}$ 
$u_{2}=v_2-\dfrac {<v_2,u_1>}{<u_1,u_1>}u_1=(-\dfrac15 \ \ \ \dfrac 25)^{T}$. Then I have to normalise which is simple action?

Is it okay until here? Or I have to use RREF for matrix A then to continue with Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: $v_2=(1 \ \ \ 1)^{T}$

Comment: Since $rank(A)=2$, RREF of $A$ is the identity matrix :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang Now after the A is identity matrix ... I can use Gram-Schmidt to proceed ?

Comment: where $v_1=(1 \ \ 0)^{T}$ and $v_2=(0 \ \ 1)^{T}$

Comment: Divide by $\;\lVert u_2\rVert$.

Comment: @Bernard Can you be more clear what did you want to say with divide by $∥u_2∥$?

Comment: I'm saying that your first approach is correct. You don't need to do anything special ('cause the second approach is wrong).

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you. So, I have only to normalise!!

Comment: I meant taking $v_2=\dfrac{u_2}{\lVert u_2\rVert}$  as the second vector.